# When saving a file, it gives an error in BLENDER , "SyntaxError: (unicode error)"

Tags: python

I already tried the backslash and add 'r'  at the beginning of the line, this does not work.I use a blender in win10, and I did not configure python in the system, because I use a different operating system to work with python.
Such a mistake

````
"Syntaxeror: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3 : truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"```


    def Save_to_STL():
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
            bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(check_existing=True, filepath="C:\Users\admin\Desktop\exported.stl", filter_glob="*.stl", ascii=False, use_mesh_modifiers=True, axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z', global_scale=1.0)
````

Comment: I tried to do so - filepath=r("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\exported.stl"); filepath="C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\exported.stl";filepath="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/exported.stl"

Comment: Sounds like you're saving the python script with an encoding other than UTF-8 which causes problems when parsing the path.

Comment: I already deleted in the title "# - * - coding: utf-8 - * -" and added, but nothing has changed, as far as I understand Blender has an inbuilt Python interpreter and a Python script editor for coding purpose, and I don’t need to what extra setting in no blender.

Comment: And you need to escape your backslashes by adding another backslash \\ or use slashes / instead.

Comment: I already tried it all - filepath=r("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\exported.stl"); filepath="C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\exported.stl";filepath="C:/Users/admin/Desktop/exported.stl"

Comment: I only have this computer with win10, for checking my code in a blender, and I can’t change anything on it, it’s possible that this is a software conflict. I can put all the code so that I can check it on my computer. "The code is very primitive"

Comment: The error is from `filepath="C:\Users...`  making the changes you have suggested will fix.  If it is addon code you may need to edit the code then restart blender (or reload scripts) to see change.

Comment: Thanks . That helped. I fixed the line, "filepath="C\\User...."  reloaded the Blender and  this error disappeared.

Comment: Now it gives such a message, I can’t understand what the problem is                                    `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=0.05, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0.175, 0, 0.09), layers=(True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False))
bpy.ops.text.run_script()
Python script fail, look in the console for now...`

Comment: As I understand it, this script started working, and then something interrupted it, but which error is not displayed

Comment: I reloaded the blender again and everything works. Thanks everyone for the help.